# ¿Cómo hago esta consulta en Laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel

```
select 
    relacion.id, 
    bim_materia.id, 
    alumnos.pnombre, 
    alumnos.apaterno, 
    alumnos.amaterno, 
    bim_materia.calificacion, 
    bim_materia.falta, 
    bim_materia.status
from 
    bim_materia 
inner join 
    calif_materia 
inner join 
    carga 
inner join 
    alumnos 
inner join 
    relacion 
where 
    bim_materia.id_calif_materia=calif_materia.id &&
    calif_materia.id_carga=carga.id && 
    calif_materia.id_relacion=$id && 
    relacion.id_maestro=(select id_maestro from relacion where id=$id) &&
    relacion.id_materia=(select id_materia from relacion where id=$id) &&
    bim_materia.num_bim=1 && 
    carga.id_alumno=alumnos.id && 
    relacion.grado=alumnos.grado && 
    relacion.grupo=alumnos.grupo
```

Comment: Hola Daniel, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] y [ask] para saber como funciona el sitio y como hacer preguntas de calidad. El titulo es la idea principal del problema pero en el cuerpo de la pregunta no puedes poner solo una consulta, has de poner la explicacion de tu problema, lo que has intentado y por que ese intento fue infructuoso. Te da fallos, errores? Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto debería funcionar.

```
//Aqui utilizas el modelo de relacion para obtener la relacion.
$relacion = Relacion::find($id);

    $items = \DB::table('bim_materia')
            ->join('calif_materia','calif_materia.id','=','bim_materia.id_calif_materia')
            ->join('carga','carga.id','=','calif_materia.id_carga')
            ->join('alumnos','alumnos.id','=','carga.id_alumno')
            ->join('relacion',function($join){
                $join->on('relacion.grado','=','alumnos.grado')
                    ->on('relacion.grupo','=','alumnos.grupo');
            })
            ->where('relacion.id_maestro',$relacion->id_maestro)
            ->where('relacion.id_materia',$relacion->id_materia)
            ->where('bim_materia.num_bim',1)
            ->where('calif_materia.id_relacion',$id)
            ->select('relacion.id', 
            'bim_materia.id', 
            'alumnos.pnombre', 
            'alumnos.apaterno', 
            'alumnos.amaterno', 
            'bim_materia.calificacion', 
            'bim_materia.falta', 
            'bim_materia.status')
            ->get();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono correctamente, te agradezco tu tiempo.

Comment: ok, con laravel es sencillo pasar una consulta sql a eloquent.

Comment: Ahí no estás usando Eloquent, simplemente es el Query builder. Son dos cosas muy distintas en Laravel.